# php sql query: AND, OR operators not working correctly

Tags: php, sql

I have a big query but i will simplify it quite a bit, with only the relevant stuff.

The Query.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM articles a 
        WHERE a.published=1 
        OR a.published=0 
        AND a.title LIKE '%$keyword%' 
        OR a.summary LIKE '%$keyword%';
```

The thing I can't get right is the AND and OR, in the example above I want to show allthe articles where published is either 0 or 1 and a.title must contain 'Lorum' ora.summary MUST contain 'Lorum'.

Currently when I run the query it gives me back all the articles, even the ones not matching the keyword, this is because of the OR operator with the a.published, I know this because when I remove that part the query works fine.

Comment: When mixing AND and OR always us brackets to control what is ANDed and what is ORed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include parenthesis in your SQL statement to group the operators e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM articles a 
        WHERE (a.published=1 OR a.published=0) 
        AND (a.title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR a.summary LIKE '%$keyword%');
```

Comment: Alternatively use `IN`, like `where a.published in (0, 1) and ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IN command to group your published into 1 logic.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles a WHERE a.published IN (1,0) AND a.title LIKE '%$keyword%' 
 OR a.summary LIKE '%$keyword%';
```